# Sql GroupBy with one more field in the result set as in the group by clause

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with different offers which are bound to a specific date. depended on the date the price changes. i want to get the cheapest deal for each date.

my problem is i use a group by like:

select price, date from deals group by date, price

to display the offer, i need more records which are not in the group by clause. the best field would be my autoid, so if a customer selects a offer with a specific price i can display this offer with all its fields using a second select.

i hope this makes it simpler to answer my question. i tried to keep it generic as possible but i have the feeling it was not described clear enough :-)

Comment: What do you want to see for the `ID` for each date?  The `MAX`, the `MIN`, some random value?

Comment: Group By generally denotes some sort of aggregate function which you do not have in your description.  Are you looking for a sum of the price on a particular date?  If you just want all of the prices and product IDs organized by date and shown at the detail level, you should use an OrderBy and not a GroupBy.

Comment: i have for each day 5 times the same product with a different price and i want to get for each day the best deal for a specific product_type.

Comment: Sorry snoop, down vote.  This is the most unintelligible problem statement I have seen from anyone with a reputation of more than 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `Id` column into the `GROUP BY` list

```
SELECT id, date, price 
FROM products 
GROUP BY id, date, price
```

Otherwise Sql Server was not able identify which id is to return for grouped by price and date rows, for instance consider two following rows:

```
1 | 10-10-2010 | 100 |
2 | 10-10-2010 | 100 |
```

Which `Id` value should be selected for row which is grouped by date and price?

```
??? | 10-10-2010 | 100 |
```

Comment: Which results set are you expect to see? Just provide input data and expected output. perhaps total price for each date? So just use `select, id, date, SUM(price) FROM table group by id, date`, or what?

Comment: sll: i dont care which. if the first or the second, i need it to select the cheapest deal. i normally dont have exact the same prices, if i do, the first match is ok.

Comment: sll: select, id, date, SUM(price) FROM table group by id, date makes sense. i will try this.

Comment: If you do not care which id select - do not select it at all

Answer (score 1):

You either need to specify an [aggregate function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) on ID or add it to your group by clause like @sll suggested.  Aggregate example:

```
SELECT MAX(id), date, price 
FROM products 
GROUP BY date, price
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the **id** from *Select* clause, you will have a list of all distinct couples of **date** and **price**.

If you add the **id** to the *Group By* clause, since it is an identity, you will obtain a row per every record in your table, so that your *Group By* clause won't be useful.

The third way is to use an aggregate function on **id** in the *Select* clause to obtain one value for every single group (the first, the min, the max, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Hi Group by is useful when you are doing count etc.

```
SELECT [Display  Billing Provider], [Display  Insurance Category]
, SUM([TOTAL RVUs]) AS RVUs_08 
, SUM([Units]) AS Units_08
, SUM(Payments) AS Payments_08
FROM dbo.ProductivityAnal_2008
GROUP BY [Display  Billing Provider],[Display  Insurance Category]
ORDER BY [Display  Billing Provider],[Display  Insurance Category]
```

Thanks Abe

Comment: @CodeSaint, I downvoted.  It seemed like you just found an example of a `GROUP BY` query online and pasted it here without trying to reference anything from the question.  I personally think you should try to tailor your answers to what has been asked.

Comment: @AbeMiessler Thanks for the clarification, No the query is from my work, In my opinion we should act as guides and point to correct references, samples and not do the work for them.

Comment: I guess that's reasonable.  I tried to reverse my downvote, but it's been too long.  If you edit your question the system will let me reverse it.